# Problema con juego de memory

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda que me llevo dentro desde que empezé este pequeño projecto, es del juego memory y lo tengo casi finalizado.
La duda que llevo desde un par de dias, es commo puedo finalizarlo porque no puedo llegar a la conclusión.
Ahora estoy en el punto donde puedo ver el reverso de las cartas, al igual que se giren al pasar cierto tiempo lo que pasa es que aunque esten correctas no se me poden giradas, y también puedo pulsar más de una. 
Alguien me podria ayudar de alguna forma?

Hasta ahora he llenado el tablero con una funcion e objectos, de tal forma de poder hacer que se vean y ser click responsive, no se si haciendolo con un array seria bastante más facil  pero la duda que más me inquieta es como hacer para que solamente se giren 2 cartas a la vez ya que la demas logica parece un poco más fácil
 ~

````
//Demanar nom

function Carta() {
    this.cartita;
    this.lletra;
    this.numero;
}

var ids = [];
var dinscarta = [];
var contador = 0;
var nom;
var dificultat;
var taulell = [];
var abc = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
var newabc = [];
var carta;
var lacarta = [];
var cartagirada1;
var cartagirada2;


function NomiDificultat() {

    do {
        nom = prompt("Indica el vostre nom");
    } while(!isNaN(nom));

    do  {
        dificultat = prompt("Indica la dificultat en la que vols jugar\n\n  0: Dificultat fàcil, 6 parelles.\n\n    1: Dificultat normal, 12 parelles.\n\n  2:Dificultat dificil, 20 parelles");
    } while (isNaN(dificultat) && (dificultat > 2 || dificultat < 0))

}


function arrayLletres () {

    Number(dificultat);

        if (dificultat == 0) {
            newabc = abc.slice(0,6);
            newabc = newabc.concat(newabc);
            console.log(newabc);

        }

            else if (dificultat == 1) {
                newabc = abc.slice(0,10);
                newabc = newabc.concat(newabc);
                console.log(newabc);


            }

                else {
                    newabc = abc.slice(0,20);
                    newabc = newabc.concat(newabc);
                    console.log(newabc);


    }
}

function randomizer() {
    newabc.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    console.log(newabc);
}


function atributObjectes () {

    if (dificultat == 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

            carta = new Carta();

            carta.cartita = "<div class='card checkered' id="+(i + 1)+">&nbsp;</div>";
            carta.lletra = newabc[i];
            carta.numero = i + 1;

            taulell.push(carta);


        }
    }
    if (dificultat == 1) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

            carta = new Carta();

            carta.cartita = "<div class='card checkered' id="+(i + 1)+">&nbsp;</div>";
            carta.lletra = newabc[i];
            carta.numero = i + 1;

            taulell.push(carta);


        }
    }
    if (dificultat == 2) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {

            carta = new Carta();

            carta.cartita = "<div class='card checkered' id="+(i + 1)+">&nbsp;</div>";
            carta.lletra = newabc[i];
            carta.numero = i + 1;

            taulell.push(carta);


        }
    }
}

function MostrarTaulell () {

if (dificultat == 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < taulell.length; i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            document.write("<div class='board' id='board'>");
        }
        if (i == 0 || i == 4 || i == 8) {
            document.write("<div>");
        }

        if (i == 4 || i == 8 || i == 12) {
            document.write("</div>");
        }
        document.write(taulell[i].cartita);

        if (i == 12) {
            document.write("</div>");
            }
        }
    }

    if (dificultat == 1) {
        for(var i = 0; i < taulell.length; i++) {

            if (i == 0) {
                document.write("<div class='board' id='board'>");
            }
            if (i == 0 || i == 5 || i == 10 || i == 15) {
                document.write("<div>");
            }

            if (i == 5 || i == 10 || i == 15 || i == 20) {
                document.write("</div>");
            }
            document.write(taulell[i].cartita);

            if (i == 20) {
                document.write("</div>");
                }
            }
        }

        if (dificultat == 2) {
            for(var i = 0; i < taulell.length; i++) {

                if (i == 0) {
                    document.write("<div class='board' id='board'>");
                }
                if (i == 0 || i == 8 || i == 16 || i == 24 || i== 32) {
                    document.write("<div>");
                }

                if (i == 8 || i == 16 || i == 24 || i == 32 || i == 40) {
                    document.write("</div>");
                }
                document.write(taulell[i].cartita);

                if (i == 40) {
                    document.write("</div>");
                    }
                }
            }
}


function checkar() {

    cartagirada1;



}


window.onload = addCardListener;    
NomiDificultat();
    arrayLletres();
        randomizer();
            atributObjectes();
                MostrarTaulell();
                    checkar();






























/**
* 'window.onload' espera que la pàgina estigui carregada per executar la funció que se li associa.
* A mode de prova inicial l'associem a la funció donada pel professorat addCardListener() perquè
* s'apreciï l'efecte de girar una carta. Quan tinguis el teu codi escrit, 'window.onload' s'haurà
* d'associar a la teva funció d'inici de joc.
*/
window.onload = addCardListener;

/**
* Funció subministrada pel professorat que agafarà cada carta i farà que escolti l'esdeveniment de ratolí
*/
function addCardListener()
{

    let cards;

    cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");

    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
    {
        cards[i].addEventListener("click", function() {clickCard(this.id)}, false);


}
}

/**
* Funció subministrada pel professorat que esperarà per paràmetre un array i el retornarà amb els elements desordenats aleatòriament.
* Com que el pas de paràmetres dels arrays és per referència, i no volem desordenar l'array d'entrada, en crearem un clon amb el mètode slice().
* Aquest nou array és el que desordenarem i retornarem.
*
* @param {array} arr
* @return {array}
*/
function shuffleArray(arr)
{
    clonedArray = arr.slice();

    return clonedArray.sort(function() {
        return Math.random() - 0.5
    })
}

/**
* Funció (incompleta) subministrada pel professorat que recull el valor de la carta clicada i fa una acció sobre el tauler.
* 
* @param {number} id - Id de la carta
*/

function clickCard(id)
{   

    // array per el id
    ids.push(id);

    console.log(ids);
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = newabc[id-1];


    console.log(dinscarta);


    // array per saber si son iguals
    dinscarta.push(newabc[id-1]);


















document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = newabc[id-1]    
    // Dona el estil de la la carta del revers
    var oldBackground = document.getElementById(id).style.background;
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = "#fff";

    // dintre de 2000 ms, es tornara a girar la carta
    setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById(id).style.background = oldBackground;}, 2000);
    // Quan s'hagi girat la carta i passin els 2000 ms es torni a posar en blanc, fins que tornem a clicar
    setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "&nbsp";}, 2000);

    }```
~

Aqui esta el css 
~```
body {
    background-color: #24461a;
}
.board {
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Standard syntax */
    text-align: center;
}

.card {
    width: 12vh;
    height: 12vh;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #921010;
    background-size: 2vh 2vh; /* Controls the size of the stripes */
    line-height: 12vh;
    font-size: 8vh;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1vh;
}

.checkered {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(.25, #a77b7b), color-stop(.25, transparent), to(transparent)),
                      -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(.25, #a77b7b), color-stop(.25, transparent), to(transparent)),
                      -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(.75, transparent), color-stop(.75, #a77b7b)),
                      -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(.75, transparent), color-stop(.75, #a77b7b));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%),
                      -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%),
                      -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%),
                      -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -o-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%),
                      -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      linear-gradient(-45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%),
                      linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%);
}

@media (max-height: 400px) {
    .card {
        width: 8vh;
        height: 8vh;
    }
}
 ~```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nos vemos de nuevo, respondí hace un tiempo a una pregunta relacionada a exactamente este mismo juego, veo que haz avanzado bastante, mira yo he estado revisando tu código y demás, y he visto que hay muchas variables que no usas y cosas que se pueden organizar, yo te recomendaría que lo organizaras antes de seguir y que quites aquellas cosas que no usaras por ejemplo algunas de las variables que están en el código, no se si lo siguiente te sirva, espero que si:

```js
//Demanar nom

function Carta() {
    this.cartita;
    this.lletra;
    this.numero;
}

var ids = [];
var dinscarta = [];
var contador = 0;
var nom;
var dificultat;
var taulell = [];
var abc = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
var newabc = [];
var carta;
var lacarta = [];
var LDS = [];
var cartagirada1;
var cartagirada2;


function NomiDificultat() {

    do {
        nom = prompt("Indica el vostre nom");
    } while(!isNaN(nom));

    do  {
        dificultat = prompt("Indica la dificultat en la que vols jugar\n\n  0: Dificultat fàcil, 6 parelles.\n\n  1: Dificultat normal, 12 parelles.\n\n  2:Dificultat dificil, 20 parelles");
    } while (isNaN(dificultat) && (dificultat > 2 || dificultat < 0))

}


function arrayLletres () {

    Number(dificultat);

    if (dificultat == 0) {
      newabc = abc.slice(0,6);
      newabc = newabc.concat(newabc);

    }

    else if (dificultat == 1) {
        
      newabc = abc.slice(0,10);
      newabc = newabc.concat(newabc);

    }

    else {
      
      newabc = abc.slice(0,20);
      newabc = newabc.concat(newabc);
      
    }
  
}

function randomizer() {
    newabc.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
}


function atributObjectes () {

    if (dificultat == 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

            carta = new Carta();
            carta.cartita = "<div class='card checkered' id="+(i + 1)+">&nbsp;</div>";
            carta.lletra = newabc[i];
            carta.numero = i + 1;
            taulell.push(carta);

        }
    }
  
    if (dificultat == 1) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

            carta = new Carta();
            carta.cartita = "<div class='card checkered' id="+(i + 1)+">&nbsp;</div>";
            carta.lletra = newabc[i];
            carta.numero = i + 1;
            taulell.push(carta);


        }
    }
  
    if (dificultat == 2) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {

            carta = new Carta();
            carta.cartita = "<div class='card checkered' id="+(i + 1)+">&nbsp;</div>";
            carta.lletra = newabc[i];
            carta.numero = i + 1;
            taulell.push(carta);

        }
    }
}

function MostrarTaulell () {

    if (dificultat == 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < taulell.length; i++) {

            if (i == 0) {
                document.write("<div class='board' id='board'>");
            }
          
            if (i == 0 || i == 4 || i == 8) {
                document.write("<div>");
            }

            if (i == 4 || i == 8 || i == 12) {
                document.write("</div>");
            }
          
            document.write(taulell[i].cartita);

            if (i == 12) {
                document.write("</div>");
            }
        }
  
    }

    if (dificultat == 1) {
        for(var i = 0; i < taulell.length; i++) {

          if (i == 0) {
            document.write("<div class='board' id='board'>");
          }
          
          if (i == 0 || i == 5 || i == 10 || i == 15) {
            document.write("<div>");
          }

          if (i == 5 || i == 10 || i == 15 || i == 20) {
            document.write("</div>");
          }
          
          document.write(taulell[i].cartita);

          if (i == 20) {
            document.write("</div>");
          }
          
        }
    }

    if (dificultat == 2) {
        for(var i = 0; i < taulell.length; i++) {

          if (i == 0) {
            document.write("<div class='board' id='board'>");
          }
          
          if (i == 0 || i == 8 || i == 16 || i == 24 || i== 32) {
            document.write("<div>");
          }

          if (i == 8 || i == 16 || i == 24 || i == 32 || i == 40) {
            document.write("</div>");
          }
          
          document.write(taulell[i].cartita);

          if (i == 40) {
            document.write("</div>");
          }
          
        }
    }
}


function checkar() {

    cartagirada1;

}


window.onload = addCardListener;    
NomiDificultat();
arrayLletres();
randomizer();
atributObjectes();
MostrarTaulell();
checkar();

/**
* Funció subministrada pel professorat que agafarà cada carta i farà que escolti l'esdeveniment de ratolí
*/
function addCardListener()
{

    let cards;
    cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");

    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
    {
        cards[i].addEventListener("click", doAClickCard, false);
    }
  
}

/**
* Funció subministrada pel professorat que esperarà per paràmetre un array i el retornarà amb els elements desordenats aleatòriament.
* Com que el pas de paràmetres dels arrays és per referència, i no volem desordenar l'array d'entrada, en crearem un clon amb el mètode slice().
* Aquest nou array és el que desordenarem i retornarem.
*
* @param {array} arr
* @return {array}
*/
function shuffleArray(arr)
{
    clonedArray = arr.slice();

    return clonedArray.sort(function() {
        return Math.random() - 0.5
    })
}

/**
* Funció (incompleta) subministrada pel professorat que recull el valor de la carta clicada i fa una acció sobre el tauler.
* 
* @param {number} id - Id de la carta
*/
function comprobarPareja(){
    
    let pair = false;
    if(cartagirada1.textContent == cartagirada2.textContent){
       
      cartagirada1.removeEventListener("click", doAClickCard);
      cartagirada2.removeEventListener("click", doAClickCard);
      pair = true;

    }
  
    return pair;
  
}
  
function doAClickCard(ev){
  
  clickCard(ev.target.id);
  
}

function clickCard(id)
{   

    if(contador < 2){
       
        // array per el id
        contador++;
        ids.push(id);
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = newabc[id-1];

        // array per saber si son iguals
        dinscarta.push(newabc[id-1]);
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = newabc[id-1];
      
        cartagirada1 = contador == 1 && !cartagirada1 ? document.getElementById(id) : cartagirada1;
        cartagirada2 = contador >= 2 && !cartagirada2 ? document.getElementById(id) : cartagirada2;

        // Dona el estil de la la carta del revers
        var oldBackground = document.getElementById(id).style.background;
        document.getElementById(id).style.background = "#fff";
           
          // dintre de 2000 ms, es tornara a girar la carta
        setTimeout(function() {
          
          if(cartagirada1 && cartagirada2 && comprobarPareja()){
            
              LDS.push(cartagirada1);
              LDS.push(cartagirada2);
              document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
            
          }else{
            
              document.getElementById(id).style.background = oldBackground;
              document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
            
          }
          
          // Quan s'hagi girat la carta i passin els 2000 ms es torni a posar en blanc, fins que tornem a clicar
             
          if(contador == 1){

            cartagirada1 = undefined;

          }else if(contador >= 2){

            cartagirada2 = undefined;

          }
          contador--;
        },2000);
      
    }

}
                   
setInterval(()=>{
          
    for(let i = 0; i < LDS.length; i++){
      
      if(LDS[i].style.background != "rgba(0,0,0,0)" || LDS[i].innerHTML != "&nbsp;"){
        
         LDS[i].style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
         LDS[i].innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
         
      }
      
    }
          
},2);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #24461a;
}
.board {
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Standard syntax */
    text-align: center;
}

.card {
    width: 12vh;
    height: 12vh;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #921010;
    background-size: 2vh 2vh; /* Controls the size of the stripes */
    line-height: 12vh;
    font-size: 8vh;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1vh;
}

.checkered {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(.25, #a77b7b), color-stop(.25, transparent), to(transparent)),
                      -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(.25, #a77b7b), color-stop(.25, transparent), to(transparent)),
                      -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(.75, transparent), color-stop(.75, #a77b7b)),
                      -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(.75, transparent), color-stop(.75, #a77b7b));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%),
                      -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%),
                      -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%),
                      -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      -o-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%),
                      -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      linear-gradient(-45deg, #a77b7b 25%, transparent 25%, transparent),
                      linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%),
                      linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #a77b7b 75%);
}

@media (max-height: 400px) {
    .card {
        width: 8vh;
        height: 8vh;
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang = "es">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset = "utf-8"></meta>
  </head>

  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

sin embargo temo decirte que lastimosamente el código tiene un enorme bug que no supe como solucionar, espero que algún otro miembro mas piloso que yo logre solucionar el bug que tiene el código... mi código funciona perfectamente pero dada cierta condición, y la condición es que la persona no se demore mucho presionando entre 1 carta y otra, ya que si demora mucho aparece el bug, siento mucho no poder hacer mas, me falta mas comprensión para ello y estuve toda la tarde viendo que podía ser...

las cosas nuevas que hay en el código son:

- una variable nueva llamada LDS
- una función nueva con nombre doAClickCard
- una función nueva con nombre comprobarPareja
- se modifico parte de la función clickCard
- se añadio un setInterval al final del código
- se hace uso de las variables contador, cartagirada1 y cartagirada2 que no se usaban para nada antes.

la explicación del código es un poco extensa... la variable LDS almacena la referencia a aquellas cartas que ya deben haber desaparecido del tablero por ser iguales.

en la función clickCard le añadí una comprobación al inicio de su ejecución, el contenido de la función se ejecutara siempre y cuando la variable contador sea menor a 2, ya que 2 es el numero de cartas máxima que puede seleccionar el usuario.

si se cumple la condición, luego de que añades la letra actual al contenido de la carta, seteamos las variables cartagirada1 y cartagirada2 dependiendo de el numero que contiene la variable contador y de si estan vacias, para el caso de la cartagirada1, si contador es igual a 1 y esta no tiene contenido aún, obtenemos el elemento correspondiente que fue clickeado y lo almacenamos en ella, de lo contrario almacenamos el valor que tenia, esto mismo hacemos con cartagirada2, solo que a esta le añadimos un valor diferente solo si contador es igual a 2 (es decir que sea la segunda carta tocada).

luego mas adelante añadimos un setTimeout de 2 segundos y en el, hacemos varias comprobaciones sencillas, estas creo que pueden ser entendidas facilmente, lo relevante es esta linea:

```
if(cartagirada1 && cartagirada2 && comprobarPareja()){

    LDS.push(cartagirada1);
    LDS.push(cartagirada2);
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "&nbsp;";

}
```

En ella llamamos a la función comprobarPareja, ella no solo estará encargada de decirnos cuando una carta coincide con otra, si no que tambien le quita los eventListener tipo click que tenga asociadas con la función doAClickCard, así evitamos que estas cartas afecten el flujo actual del programa ya que ya no necesitan ser mostradas (Aunque siguen ahí, solo que están escondidas).

la función doAClickCard, es creada y usada simplemente para poder que cada evento tipo click de cada una de las cartas asociada a el pueda ser cancelado con su referencia, (cosa que no se puede hacer con una función anónima sin asignarla a una variable), ademas en ella ejecuto la función clickCard haciendo uso de datos del evento, es muy importante.

El setInterval del final del código que se ejcuta cada 2ms se usa por si depronto se han quedado de manera erronea algunos fondos de algunas cartas, esta comprueba cada uno de los valores almacenados en la variable LDS y mira si su contenido HTML es diferente a un espacio en blanco o si su background (Que debería ser transparente no lo es), en cualquiera de los dos casos, si se cumple uno hacemos transparente el fondo de ese elemento y también a su innerHTML le ponemos un   para que se vea mas fluido el cambio de texto que contenía.

Las variables cartagirada1 y cartagirada2 podrian ser consideradas variables temporales, ya que estas variables se les es reseteado el valor a undefined una vez la carta seleccionada es giradas de nuevo de reverso o desaparece.

**NOTA:** para mejor calidad verlo en el snippet ampliado.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Esta perfecto. La cosa es que ya envié el juego hace días y la verdad es que me supe envolver mucho con lo que tenia. Es verdad que tenia mucha runa, però lo pude solucionar. Se tiene que decir que ni de coña es tan perfecto como el tuyo, pero pude sacar un 8 en ese proyecto